# dynamically generate tool-tip on hover on any cell of a grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, tooltip

I have not worked on Silverlight at all and have been stuck in one of the requirement for some application which runs on Silverlight.

**Requirement:**
I want to display Tool-tip on my grid which have below Columns and on hover over ID column, I want to display tool-tip for each row separately based on the ID for that row.

[This is how Grid Looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oyG1.png)

I have the below code for Data-Grid:

```
<UserControl xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls" 
    x:Class="MYAPP.View.Pages.MyPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:MYAPP.View"
    xmlns:pag="clr-namespace:MYAPP.View.Pages"
    xmlns:ctl="clr-namespace:MYAPP.Controls;assembly=MYAPP.Controls"
    xmlns:log="clr-namespace:MYAPP.Logic.WCF.Services;assembly=MYAPP.Logic"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    >
    <Grid Name="grdMain">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ctl:FieldHelp x:Name="grdMyGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="40,10"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding PendingRequests, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       DoubleClick="grdMyGrid_DoubleClick"
                       CurrentCellChanged="grdChildren_CurrentCellChanged"
                       Visibility="{Binding PendingRequestsDetail, ConverterParameter=false, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <ctl:FieldHelp.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ShortDateStringConverter}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <data:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Process, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="False" IsThreeState="False"/>
            </ctl:FieldHelp.Columns>
        </ctl:FieldHelp>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have no Idea on how to work on the requirement."
Searching on net didn't gave me proper solution to which I end up getting the same **Name** in tool-tip as that of row's cell.
[Only Get Name in tool-tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz5eI.png)

```
    <ctl:FieldHelp x:Name="grdMyGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="40,10"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding PendingRequests, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       DoubleClick="grdMyGrid_DoubleClick"
                       CurrentCellChanged="grdChildren_CurrentCellChanged"
                       Visibility="{Binding PendingRequestsDetail, ConverterParameter=false, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <ctl:FieldHelp.Columns>

                <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True"  >
                   <data:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="data:DataGridCell" >
                            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}"  />
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </data:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </data:DataGridTextColumn>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RelativeName, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ShortDateStringConverter}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <data:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Process, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="False" IsThreeState="False"/>
            </ctl:FieldHelp.Columns>
        </ctl:FieldHelp>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But I want to dynamically bind the tool-tip which shows data based on the record ID-on which I have hovered.

[Tool-tip should be seen like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEEVZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would add a style that sets up your Tooltip

```
<ctl:FieldHelp...>
  <ctl:FieldHelp.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ID, StringFormat=Tooltip for ID:{0}}" />
    </Style>
  </ctl:FieldHelp.Resources>
  <!-- The rest of your column etc -->
```

However, if the FieldHelp control (`ctl:FieldHelp`) isn't a sub-classed DataGrid then I don't think this solution will work for you.

Comment: Hi @MarkGreen,

I have used below code as suggested, but no tool-tip appearing for me :

'<ctl:FieldHelp.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="data:DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding ID, StringFormat='Tooltip for ID: \{0\}'}"/>
                </Style>
            </ctl:FieldHelp.Resources>'

Comment: I think you probably need to talk to whoever designed the FieldHelp control and ask them where is the best place to put the tooltip style for DataGridCells. It looks like it is a bespoke control.